# Sample example - Microsoft regarding Monetize your Office 365 add-in through Microsoft Commercial Marketplace

Tags: office-js, office-addins, office-store, office-dialog-api

I have received an email from Microsoft regarding Monetize your Office 365 add-in through Microsoft Commercial Marketplace.
I have an excel content pane add-in already listed in app source and is paid, I want to Monetize it through Microsoft.
Is there a complete end to end example available for

1. Implementing ISV Service?
2. add-in authenticate a user?
3. Implementing SaaS fulfilment APIs?

Add-in user could be a work/school or Microsoft personal account holder.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by #1 or #3. For #2, see the official documentation at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/overview-authn-authz

Answer (score -1):

We have a team currently developing code samples, these are on track on be completed in January.

Until then, we recommend you refer to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/store/monetize-addins-through-microsoft-commercial-marketplace)

Comment: I went through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/monetize-addins-through-microsoft-commercial-marketplace, it says "Transactable SaaS apps are only purchasable using a work or school account. If you want to sell your add-in to Microsoft account-based users, you should consider implementing your own billing model." **My question is why Microsoft does not support Microsoft account-based users? Are you planing to support in future?**